# How can I increase the resolution of my input video for my real time Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, resolution, object-detection-api

I am having trouble increasing the resolution in my input video for real time object detection. I have tried increasing the input resolution of the video read in, but the output gives me an error.

I am streaming the video using a webcam program

The only dimensions that work are 640 x 480. Anything bigger gives me an output error. The resolution will only stay 1920 x 1080 until before the frame window, then it switches back to 640 x 480 and gives me an error when the video saves.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util 
import cv2 as cv
from time import time

import serial

refPoints = []

# draw ROI
def image_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPoints

    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPoints = [(x, y)]
    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPoints.append((x, y))


# run inference on single image
def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph, sess):
    with graph.as_default():
        boxes = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        scores = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        classes = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

        rboxes, rscores, rclasses = sess.run([boxes, scores, classes], feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

    return rboxes[0], rscores[0], rclasses[0]



def main():

    # 0 - load model
    PATH_TO_MODEL = 'C:\\frozen_inference_graph.pb'
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_MODEL, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

    # 1 - define video streamer & serial port
    streamer = 0
    out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 20, (1920, 1080)) #previously 25.0, (640, 480)
    port = 'COM4'
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)

    # 2 - draw region of interest (ROI)
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(cv.CAP_DSHOW)
    clone = frame.copy()
    cv.namedWindow('frame')
    cv.resizeWindow('frame', (1920, 1080)) 
    cv.setMouseCallback('frame', image_crop)
    print(frame.shape)#
    print('ROI selecting...')
    while True:
        cv.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r'):
            print('ROI selection reset.')
            frame = clone.copy()
        elif cv.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('c'):
            print('ROI selected.')
            cap.release()
            break
    if len(refPoints) == 2:
        cv.rectangle(frame, refPoints[0], refPoints[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print('only one ROI allowed.')
        cap.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        return -1
    # 3 - run inferences on ROI
    t1 = 0
    t2 = 0
    t3 = 0
    i = 0
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(streamer)
    cv.namedWindow('frame')
    cv.resizeWindow('frame', (1920, 1080)) 
    while(True):
        # image reading & cropping
        t0 = time()        
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            break
        cropped = frame[refPoints[0][1]:refPoints[1][1], refPoints[0][0]:refPoints[1][0]]
        dt = time()-t0
        t1 += dt
        # image inference
        t0 = time()
        image = cropped.copy()
        boxes, scores, classes = run_inference_for_single_image(image, detection_graph, sess)
        boxes = boxes[scores>0.95]
        classes = classes[scores>0.95]
        boxes1 = boxes[classes==1]
        boxes2 = boxes[classes==2]
        dt = time()-t0
        t2 += dt
        t0 = time()
        cv.rectangle(frame, refPoints[0], refPoints[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        if len(boxes1):
            #vis_util.draw_bounding_boxes_on_image_array(image, boxes)
            cv.rectangle(frame, refPoints[0], refPoints[1], (0, 0, 255), 4)
            ser.write(b'1')
        else:
            ser.write(b'0')
        #if len(boxes2):
        #    cv.rectangle(frame, refPoints[0], refPoints[1], (255, 0, 0), 4)
        #print(frame.shape)

        #print(frame.shape)#
        cv.imshow('frame', frame)
        out.write(frame)
        dt = time()-t0
        t3 += dt
        i += 1
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    print("image reading: average %f sec/frame"%(t1/i))
    print("image processing: average %f sec/frame"%(t2/i))
    print("image showing/saving: average %f sec/frame"%(t3/i))
    ser.close()
    sess.close()
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can set the webcam resolution as given below, but which model are you using for detection if you are using any ssd models then the input image will be resized to smaller like 224*224.                                                                     
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)